# GLKit on iOS5: setting texture prevents other drawing

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, textures

I am attempting to do some very simple 2D drawing with GLKit, including using a texture. However, if I load the texture, but don't even use it in the drawing, somehow it prevents the drawing from taking place!

Here is my setup code:

```
-(void) setup {

  effect = [[GLKBaseEffect alloc] init];

  // comment this out - drawing takes place
  texture = [GLKTextureLoader textureWithCGImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"arrow.png"].CGImage options:nil error: nil];
  if (texture) {
    effect.texture2d0.envMode = GLKTextureEnvModeReplace;
    effect.texture2d0.target = GLKTextureTarget2D;
    effect.texture2d0.name = texture.name;
  };
  // end of comment this out...

  effect.transform.projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeOrtho(0.0, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height, 0.0, 1, -1);

}
```

Here is my drawing code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

  GLKVector2 vertices[4];
  GLKVector4 colors[4];

  vertices[0] = GLKVector2Make(20.0, 30.0);
  vertices[1] = GLKVector2Make(120.0, 45.0);
  vertices[2] = GLKVector2Make(70.0, 88.0);
  vertices[3] = GLKVector2Make(20.0, 80.0);

  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

    colors[i] = GLKVector4Make(0.3, 0.8, 0.5, 1.0);
  };

  glClearColor(0.85, 0.05, 0.1, 1.0);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  [effect prepareToDraw];

  glEnable(GL_BLEND);
  glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

  glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribColor);

  glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertices);
  glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribColor, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, colors);

  glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 3);


  glDisableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
  glDisableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribColor);

  glDisable(GL_BLEND);
}
```

Comment: Does something basic like clearing the color buffer with something other than black give you the expected results? Is it possible that `GLKTextureLoader` is enabling texturing just by you uploading the texture? What do you see if you upload a texture that's a solid color and set it to clamp to edge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For debugging OpenGL, run the code in Debug mode, then pause it and choose "Capture OpenGL ES frame" from the menu bar. This allows you to step through your drawing code and see the OpenGL state after each call. Therefore, you can compare the states between when you do the setup code and when you don't do it, and can pin down the bug.

For the problem itself: Setting the texture2d property of the effect is already enough to use the texture. It is automatically used in the drawing if you put it there. In `[effect prepareToDraw]`, the whole state of the effect is applied - including the specified texture.

Comment: Hi Etan, I think I may have misunderstood the nature of GLKBaseEffect  - if you add a texture to an effect, does this stop any other kind of drawing (i.e. filled areas and lines)? If that is the case, how is it possible to combine textures and drawing?

Comment: I'm investigating a similar issue. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404779/using-glkit-and-opengl-es-how-to-draw-two-triangles-one-textured-another-soli  Have you had any luck? So far the only way I can figure out how to do this is to have another base effect instance and call prepareToDraw on that